# Can't Connect to the TryHackMe OpenVPN server

Tags: openvpn

So i am trying to connect to the TryHackMe virtual rooms and i need to connect to their OpenVPN server but i face the problem that i really don't understand it says:

```
Mon May 18 23:50:14 2020 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon May 18 23:50:14 2020 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

i tried to change the connection from UDP to TCP as some suggested on similar questions but it's not as well and it gives me saying:

```
Mon May 18 23:55:16 2020 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1194 failed: Unknown error
```